# How to create email account on cpanel using php

Tags: php, email, cpanel

I am trying to create email account in cpanel using php like `test@mydomain.com`. I tried cpanel api's , xml api etc.

```
fopen ("http://$cpuser:$cppass@$cpdomain:2083/frontend/$cpskin/mail/doaddpop.html?email=$euser&domain=$edomain&password=$epass&quota=$equota", "r");
```

this gives me error `"Cannot create email account. Possible reasons: "fopen" function allowed on your server, PHP is running in SAFE mode"`

but not worked any more. can any one tell me what is the problem exactly, is there any settings I have to set up in server or any thing else.

thank you in advance :)

Comment: I suggest you use now modern way by using cpanel live api, refer : https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/SDK/Guide+to+the+LiveAPI+System+-+PHP+Class

Comment: If your server is running in "safe" mode, your server is dangerously insecure. It was removed in PHP 5.4, which means your server's version of PHP must be 5.3 or lower, which means you're about two years past end-of-life in the best case. Time to update.

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests probably you have allow_url_fopen on the disabled_functions list on your php.ini (default location would be /usr/lib/php.ini).

Alternatively you can use the perl script provided by cPanel to create an email address from command line:

```
/scripts/addpop user@domain.com password quota#

Example:
/scripts/addpop contact@abc.com password 1024 (this will create the email address contact@abc.com with the password 'password' and with 1024M (1G) as quota
```

If you do want to use that in a php script then use the php shell_exec() function to execute the command above and you're good to go.

I would advise against enabling allow_url_fopen in php.ini long termn and leave it like that since it might pose security risks to your server.